# Splitting two messy vectors in a data frame into one common column

Tags: r, split, dplyr, reshape, data-cleaning

Sample of dataset:

```
library(dplyr)
sample <- structure(list(Rank = c(15, 17, 20, 2, 16, 8, 21, 5, 13, 31, 22, 18, 2, 19, 11, 11, 8, 7, 12, 9, 5, 23, 17, 16, 15, 14, 4, 20, 13, 2), Athlete = c("François Gourmet(BEL)", "Agustín Félix(ESP)", "Keisuke Ushiro", "Michael Schrader", "Pieter Braun", "Laurent Hernu(FRA)", "Dmitriy Karpov", "Laurent Hernu(FRA)", "Thomas van der Plaetsen", "Attila Szabó", "Nadir El Fassi", "Eduard Mikhan", "Leonel Suárez", "Janek Õiglane", "Hans van Alphen(BEL)", "Roman Šebrle", "André Niklaus(GER)", "Pascal Behrenbruch", "Pieter Braun", "Oleksandr Yurkov(UKR)", "Eelco Sintnicolaas", "Brent Newdick", "Kim Kun-woo", "Akihiko Nakamura", "Bastien Auzeil", "Frédéric Xhonneux", "Janek Õiglane", "Keisuke Ushiro", "Roman Šebrle", "Rico Freimuth"), Total = c(7974, 7749, 7498, 8670, 7890, 8280, 7550, 8218, 8069, 7610, 7922, 7968, 8640, 7581, 8034, 8266, 8020, 8211, 8114, 8264, 8298, 7915, 7860, 7745, 7922, 7616, 8371, 7532, 8069, 8564), `100m` = c(10.67, 11.17, 11.53, 10.73, 11.22, 10.97, 11.24, 11.2, 11.2, 11.15, 11.12, 10.97, 11.13, 11.51, 11.11, 11.16, 11.19, 11.08, 11.11, 10.93, 10.76, 11.11, 11.11, 10.86, 11.35, 11.28, 11.08, 11.51, 11.25, 10.53), LJ = c(7.15, 7.12, 6.64, 7.85, 7.17, 7.31, 6.86, 7.22, 7.79, 7.09, 7.26, 7.42, 7.24, 6.78, 7.35, 7.8, 7.21, 6.8, 7.29, 7.37, 7.29, 7.42, 7.24, 7.26, 6.87, 7.21, 7.33, 6.73, 7.3, 7.48), SP = c(13.74, 13.29, 13.43, 14.56, 14.48, 14.43, 15.69, 13.99, 12.76, 13.92, 13.62, 14.15, 15.2, 14.43, 14.67, 14.98, 13.87, 16.01, 13.9, 15.15, 14.13, 14.35, 12.96, 11.67, 15.23, 12.92, 15.13, 14.93, 15.2, 14.85), HJ = c(1.85, 2.03, 1.96, 1.99, 1.93, 2.03, 1.93, 2.03, 2.17, 1.84, 1.99, 1.96, 2.11, 1.92, 1.88, 2.11, 1.97, 1.93, 2.04, 1.97, 1.93, 1.99, 1.96, 1.95, 1.96, 2.03, 2.05, 1.89, 2.05, 1.99), `400m` = c(47.98, 52.08, 51.43, 47.66, 48.54, 49.31, 52.01, 48.95, 49.46, 49.79, 51.35, 48.8, 48, 50.95, 48.52, 50.42, 49.95, 49.9, 48.24, 49.45, 48.35, 50.1, 49.24, 47.81, 50.36, 49.04, 49.58, 50.85, 51.18, 48.41), `110mh` = c(15.02, 14.75, 15.35, 14.29, 14.67, 14.01, 14.64, 14.15, 14.79, 14.65, 14.9, 14.82, 14.45, 15.33, 14.77, 14.44, 14.5, 14.33, 14.37, 14.41, 14.42, 14.82, 14.95, 14.72, 14.59, 15.75, 14.56, 15.43, 14.75, 13.68), DT = c(39.87, 43.67, 47.64, 46.44, 42.59, 43.93, 47.1, 46.13, 37.2, 43.75, 42.25, 48, 44.71, 40.94, 44.3, 46.3, 42.68, 48.56, 42.09, 48.1, 42.23, 43.6, 39.53, 33.48, 46.86, 38.62, 42.11, 46.85, 46.93, 51.17), PV = c(5, 5, 4.6, 5, 4.7, 5.1, 4.8, 4.9, 5.1, 4.4, 4.8, 4.6, 5, 4.6, 4.3, 4.6, 5.1, 4.9, 4.9, 5, 5.2, 4.8, 4.9, 4.7, 4.8, 4.7, 5.1, 4.7, 4.8, 4.8), JT = c(57.73, 56.69, 63.28, 65.67, 59.26, 59.9, 46.91, 59.63, 58.91, 59.56, 57.65, 50.74, 75.19, 68.51, 65.71, 65.61, 57.55, 66.5, 56.95, 58.63, 61.07, 51.52, 53.33, 53.57, 60.8, 50.18, 71.73, 56.52, 67.28, 62.34), `1500m` = c(265.51, 288.27, 291.9, 265.38, 278.4, 277.41, 298.41, 268.4, 285.86, 285.64, 256.51, 273.71, 267.25, 283.06, 262.5, 290.33, 268.8, 276.64, 272.46, 278.43, 265.4, 270.57, 255.63, 256.36, 279.8, 262.71, 279.24, 283.51, 296.5, 281.57), Year = structure(c(4L, 4L, 9L, 7L, 9L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 8L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 8L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 9L,     3L, 9L, 8L, 6L, 9L), .Label = c("2001", "2003", "2005", "2007",     "2009", "2011", "2013", "2015", "2017"), class = "factor"),     Nationality = c(NA, NA, "Japan(JPN)", "Germany(GER)", "Netherlands(NED)",     NA, "Kazakhstan(KAZ)", NA, "Belgium(BEL)", "Hungary", "France",     "Belarus(BLR)", "Cuba", "Estonia(EST)", NA, "Czech Republic",     NA, "Germany(GER)", "Netherlands(NED)", NA, "Netherlands(NED)",     "New Zealand", "South Korea(KOR)", "Japan(JPN)", "France(FRA)",     NA, "Estonia(EST)", "Japan(JPN)", "Czech Republic(CZE)",     "Germany(GER)"), Notes = c(NA, NA, NA, "PB", NA, NA, NA,     NA, NA, NA, "SB", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,     "PB", "NR", NA, "SB", NA, "PB", NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("Rank", "Athlete", "Total", "100m", "LJ", "SP", "HJ", "400m", "110mh", "DT", "PV", "JT", "1500m", "Year", "Nationality", "Notes"), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

# A tibble: 30 x 16
    Rank                 Athlete Total `100m`    LJ    SP    HJ `400m` `110mh`    DT    PV    JT `1500m`   Year      Nationality Notes
   <dbl>                   <chr> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <fctr>            <chr> <chr>
 1    15   François Gourmet(BEL)  7974  10.67  7.15 13.74  1.85  47.98   15.02 39.87   5.0 57.73  265.51   2007             <NA>  <NA>
 2    17      Agustín Félix(ESP)  7749  11.17  7.12 13.29  2.03  52.08   14.75 43.67   5.0 56.69  288.27   2007             <NA>  <NA>
 3    20          Keisuke Ushiro  7498  11.53  6.64 13.43  1.96  51.43   15.35 47.64   4.6 63.28  291.90   2017       Japan(JPN)  <NA>
 4     2        Michael Schrader  8670  10.73  7.85 14.56  1.99  47.66   14.29 46.44   5.0 65.67  265.38   2013     Germany(GER)    PB
 5    16            Pieter Braun  7890  11.22  7.17 14.48  1.93  48.54   14.67 42.59   4.7 59.26  278.40   2017 Netherlands(NED)  <NA>
 6     8      Laurent Hernu(FRA)  8280  10.97  7.31 14.43  2.03  49.31   14.01 43.93   5.1 59.90  277.41   2001             <NA>  <NA>
 7    21          Dmitriy Karpov  7550  11.24  6.86 15.69  1.93  52.01   14.64 47.10   4.8 46.91  298.41   2011  Kazakhstan(KAZ)  <NA>
 8     5      Laurent Hernu(FRA)  8218  11.20  7.22 13.99  2.03  48.95   14.15 46.13   4.9 59.63  268.40   2003             <NA>  <NA>
 9    13 Thomas van der Plaetsen  8069  11.20  7.79 12.76  2.17  49.46   14.79 37.20   5.1 58.91  285.86   2011     Belgium(BEL)  <NA>
10    31            Attila Szabó  7610  11.15  7.09 13.92  1.84  49.79   14.65 43.75   4.4 59.56  285.64   2009          Hungary  <NA>
# ... with 20 more rows
```

I have two character vectors, "Athlete and "Nationality", in my dataset where some entries have country codes in brackets attached at the end. I want to be able to split only the country codes from these two vectors into a new variable, say "countrycode", while getting rid of the brackets at the same time. I'm not sure what the best way or syntax to go about splitting would be though - dplyr::separate possibly? Though I'm uncertain how to incorporate the combinations of characters in the country codes within the brackets during the split, and the fact that some entries don't need splitting.

I would then do something like this after to remove the brackets from the new variable.

```
sample$countrycode<- gsub(pattern="\\(",replacement="",x=sample$countrycode)
sample$countrycode<- gsub(pattern="\\)",replacement="",x=sample$countrycode)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this works for you:

```
library(dplyr)

res <- sample %>% mutate(
    countrycode = case_when(
        is.na(Nationality) & grepl('\\(', Athlete) ~ gsub('.*?\\((.*)\\)', '\\1', Athlete),
        grepl('\\(', Nationality) ~ gsub('.*?\\((.*)\\)', '\\1', Nationality),
        TRUE ~ Nationality
    )
)
```

sample output:

```
res %>% select(Athlete, Nationality, countrycode)
# # A tibble: 30 x 3
#    Athlete                 Nationality      countrycode
# <chr>                   <chr>            <chr>     
# 1 François Gourmet(BEL)   NA               BEL       
# 2 Agustín Félix(ESP)      NA               ESP       
# 3 Keisuke Ushiro          Japan(JPN)       JPN       
# 4 Michael Schrader        Germany(GER)     GER       
# 5 Pieter Braun            Netherlands(NED) NED       
# 6 Laurent Hernu(FRA)      NA               FRA       
# 7 Dmitriy Karpov          Kazakhstan(KAZ)  KAZ       
# 8 Laurent Hernu(FRA)      NA               FRA       
# 9 Thomas van der Plaetsen Belgium(BEL)     BEL       
# 10 Attila Szabó            Hungary          Hungary   
# # ... with 20 more rows
```

Remove the `TRUE ~ Nationality` to extract only country code as commented by Frank:

```
sample %>% mutate(
    countrycode = case_when(
        is.na(Nationality) & grepl('\\(', Athlete) ~ gsub('.*?\\((.*)\\)', '\\1', Athlete),
        grepl('\\(', Nationality) ~ gsub('.*?\\((.*)\\)', '\\1', Nationality)
    ))
```

Comment: Thanks; wasn't sure how case_when worked. Btw, unclear if TRUE ~ Nationality is desired for cases where neither column contains a code. Either way, OP can look up those codes I guess, with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-3

Comment: @Frank, thanks. It seems very likely that I misunderstood the OP's requirement. I edited the answer to keep only country codes.

Comment: That's done the job, thanks. Do you have any recommended code to remove the bracketed country codes in the Nationality/Athlete columns after? Regular expression syntax is still pretty new and confusing to me admittedly.

Comment: @VYu. I'll give you an example: `gsub('\\(.*?\\)', '', 'Germany(GER)')` will give only `'Germany'` as `'\\(.*?\\)'` will match a pair of brackets and letters in between and replace them to `''`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

An ugly approach would be to use `sub`:

```
library(data.table)
DT = data.table(sample)

patt = "^.*\\((.{3})\\).*$"; rp = "\\1"
DT[Athlete %like% patt, cc := sub(patt, rp, Athlete)]
DT[Nationality %like% patt, cc := sub(patt, rp, Nationality)]
```

Something like `str_extract` from the stringr package would probably be cleaner if you're already working with tidyverse packages. Also, for the dplyr analogue to the code above, maybe look at the `case_when` function. (I am not familiar enough with these tools to know the exact syntax.)

The result looks like...

```
> DT[, .(Athlete, Nationality, cc)]
                    Athlete         Nationality  cc
 1:   François Gourmet(BEL)                  NA BEL
 2:      Agustín Félix(ESP)                  NA ESP
 3:          Keisuke Ushiro          Japan(JPN) JPN
 4:        Michael Schrader        Germany(GER) GER
 5:            Pieter Braun    Netherlands(NED) NED
 6:      Laurent Hernu(FRA)                  NA FRA
 7:          Dmitriy Karpov     Kazakhstan(KAZ) KAZ
 8:      Laurent Hernu(FRA)                  NA FRA
 9: Thomas van der Plaetsen        Belgium(BEL) BEL
10:            Attila Szabó             Hungary  NA
11:          Nadir El Fassi              France  NA
12:           Eduard Mikhan        Belarus(BLR) BLR
13:           Leonel Suárez                Cuba  NA
14:           Janek Õiglane        Estonia(EST) EST
15:    Hans van Alphen(BEL)                  NA BEL
16:            Roman Šebrle      Czech Republic  NA
17:      André Niklaus(GER)                  NA GER
18:      Pascal Behrenbruch        Germany(GER) GER
19:            Pieter Braun    Netherlands(NED) NED
20:   Oleksandr Yurkov(UKR)                  NA UKR
21:      Eelco Sintnicolaas    Netherlands(NED) NED
22:           Brent Newdick         New Zealand  NA
23:             Kim Kun-woo    South Korea(KOR) KOR
24:        Akihiko Nakamura          Japan(JPN) JPN
25:          Bastien Auzeil         France(FRA) FRA
26:       Frédéric Xhonneux                  NA  NA
27:           Janek Õiglane        Estonia(EST) EST
28:          Keisuke Ushiro          Japan(JPN) JPN
29:            Roman Šebrle Czech Republic(CZE) CZE
30:           Rico Freimuth        Germany(GER) GER
                    Athlete         Nationality  cc
```

Answer (score 1):

This simple solution works too.

```
library(stringr)
data1$country_code <- sapply(data1$Nationality, function(x) unlist(stri_extract_all(str = x, regex = '([A-Z]+)'))[2])

        Nationality country_code
1:               NA           NA
2:               NA           NA
3:       Japan(JPN)          JPN
4:     Germany(GER)          GER
5: Netherlands(NED)          NED
6:               NA           NA
```